# If $Q(v)=\left(D^{2} f(a) v, v\right)$ is indefinite form, then prove that $f$ has a saddle point at $a$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

It is asked that $Q(v)=\left(D^{2} f(a) v, v\right)$ is indefinite form then I have to show that $f$ has a saddle point at $a$.

I am having difficulty in understanding the problem.
What does $Q(v)$ represents? I think the bracket there is for inner product.
And what is meant by the indefinite form here?

Comment: Assuming you're working in an inner product space $V$, then $Q:V\to\mathbb R,~v\mapsto (\mathrm D^2f(a)v,v)$ is a quadratic form. The brackets are indeed the inner product. A quadratic form $Q$ is called indefinite if there are vectors $v_1,v_2\in V$ such that $Q(v_1)>0$ and $Q(v_2)<0$.